# How to update some rows in database table while processing data from that same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write an update statement to update bunch of values in database table.

First a bit of an intro. Our client is from industry of transport and logistics. They provide a service of transport (construction material) between people who need construction material and those who have transportation companies and offer transportation service, truckers.

Driver can get an inquiry, where he needs to do some deliveries and pickups. For example, one inquiry can consist of three tours. He can start tour, pick up material, deliver material, pick up waste (at the same construction site where he drop material), start new subtour, deliver waste, pick up material, start new subtour, deliver material and subtour, and finally end entire tour.

There is also websocket which pings drivers location (mobile client) and writes down longitude and latitude in `tour_log` table. So, location is tracked every 30 sec.

On the image, you can see how section of that table looks like. That table has over million records.

[image]

The web (spring-boot) service, when driver finishes subtour, is not saving to the database for which subtour the driver ended subtour (SUBTOUR_END). I updated that service, but our client, will want some reports for tours and inquiries for some earlier period. I need to perform an update to be able to complete Report functionality.

So, to the main point. I do have a query which is obviously not working. I cannot update a table from which I'm querying data in the same time.

```
UPDATE tour_log 
SET tour_id = (SELECT tour_id FROM tour_log A 
               WHERE tour_log_id = (SELECT (tour_log_id) 
                                    FROM tour_log B 
                                    WHERE tour_id IS NULL AND log = "SUBTOUR_END" AND A.tour_log_id = B.tour_log_id - 1)) 
WHERE log = "SUBTOUR_END" AND tour_id is null AND inquiry_id = 7519646; -- I'm doing update for single inquiry only
```

Anyone to give me a hint on how to go about this?

Comment: Open Manual Reference and find "UPDATE Syntax" article, read "Multiple-table update" paragraph.

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.  The innermost subquery suggests that `tour_id` is going to be `NULL`, so I don't think your logic does anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
UPDATE tour_log t1
JOIN tour_log t2 ON t1.truck_id = t2.truck_id 
                AND t1.tour_log_id > t2.tour_log_id
LEFT JOIN tour_log t3 ON t1.truck_id = t3.truck_id 
                AND t1.tour_log_id > t3.tour_log_id
                AND t3.tour_log_id > t2.tour_log_id
SET t1.tour_id = t2.tour_id
WHERE t1.log = 'SUBTOUR_END'
  AND t3.tour_log_id IS NULL
```

I.e. copy `tour_id` to the row with `'SUBTOUR_END'` from previous adjacent row (`t3` is used for to check that there is no row between them).

`tour_log_id`, not `timestamp`, is used for ordering because the last one may have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, spasiba Akina. But I don't know why you use truck_id in this query and why in where clause you didn't write t1.tour_id IS NULL? Since I'm 3rd year student and we had sql as a course, I don't quite understand this query. Can you break it down in a bit more detail if that is not a big of a problem for you :)

Comment: @Mike *why you use truck_id* As I understand one tour is made by one track. And a track cannot perform 2 tours at the same time. So when a row with some track_id and NULL in tour_id exists then it is a row which must be updated. I do not see another mark for to find a group of rows which the row with NULL must be attached to. If it exists tell me about this. *why in where clause you didn't write t1.tour_id IS NULL?* You may add it by yourself - this is minor detail for an algorithm and it is not a problem.

Comment: @Mike *I don't quite understand this query.* As I have explained in the answer, I search an adjacent pair of rows where the latter one is SUBTOUR_END. Look at your screenshot. For such row with tour_log_id=736868 (this will be a row in `t1`) an adjacent row have tour_log_id=736867 (this will be a row in `t2`) - the only row where there is no a row between (for a row in `t3` - the condition `t3.tour_log_id IS NULL` checks this, only for `t2.tour_log_id=736867` it will give NULL, for any other row it will give a value). The same for tour_log_id=736861 and tour_log_id=736860, which are marked.